# O que é uma instrução de máquina goto e qual a diferença para jump e para um comando goto de linguagem de alto nível?

Tags: terminologia, assembly, goto

De *The Elements of Computing Systems*, tradução minha:

> Linguagens de máquina possuem diversas variantes de instruções *goto* (*"vá para"*) condicionais e incondicionais, bem como *statements* de declaração de rótulo (*label*) que marcam o destino do *goto*.

Uma instrução *goto* pelo que entendi é uma instrução de linguagem de máquina para efetuar *branching* ou desvio para uma determinada posição do programa, que pode ser condicional ou incondicional.

Instruções de uma linguagem de máquina hipotética como JEQ ("Jump if equal"), JNE, JGE ("Jump if greater than or equal"), JLE, JG, JL, JZ ("Jump if zero") além da JMP que é incondicional então são todas instruções *goto*? É um termo que denomina coletivamente essas instruções de máquina?

Existe diferença entre uma instrução *goto* e um *statement* `goto <label>;` usado em linguagens de alto nível, como C?

Acredito que sim, pois penso que o *statement* pode ser otimizado pelo compilador para se tornar um desvio condicional dependendo do contexto, por exemplo:

```
if (x == 0) goto label;
```

O trecho acima poderia ser traduzido para uma instrução JZ (Jump if zero) e não uma simples JMP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*goto* com esse nome não existe em linguagem de máquina ou Assembly. O texto deve estar falando de condicional de forma geral e usando a palavra que as pessoas conhecem em alto nível.

Podemos dizer que todas essas instruções citadas são de *branching* e de certa maneira uma forma de *goto*.

O `goto` de alto nível é, em quase todas as linguagens, o `JMP` (*jump* incondicional). Assim como o `break`, `continue` e possivelmente outras formas em algumas linguagens. Então um `goto` de C virará uma instrução `JMP` depois de compilado.

De fato, é possível alguma implementação de compilador transformar em desvio condicional direto, evitando que se faça o desvio normal do `if` que é condicional e depois o incondicional. Então poderia ter só o `JZ`. Mas desconheço qualquer linguagem que obrigue isto ocorrer.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Assembly/Conceptual.md).